# PL/SQL Oracle Mutant table-how to encounter this issue plz?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

th request is to assure that in the city we have only one branch,
Banch (idBranch(PK), city) for update and insert

the idea I got is to create a temporary table having all the data of the first one so i can escape the ora errors this is the code I wrote, i'm facing the error PL/SQL: ORA-00903 and I'm not so sure if one trigger can do he job in this case since it should be working for inserting and updating. I need your advice please, thank you.

```
  ` CREATE TABLE TEMP_BRANCH AS SELECT NumBranch, CITY FROM BRANCH;
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkUniqueBranchPerCity
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BRANCH  
    REFERENCING
        NEW AS nextLine
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    LOCK TABLE TEMP_BRANCH IN ROW SHARE MODE;

     FOR line IN (SELECT * FROM TEMP_BRANCH) LOOP 
       IF :nextLine.City = line.City  THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR;
       END IF;
    END LOOP;

    DELETE * FROM TEMP_BRANCH;
    END;
   / `
```

Answer (score 0):

ORA-00903 is "Invalid table name". I suspect it's caused because you put a colon in front of `nextLine`, i.e. you wrote

```
IF :nextLine.City = line.City  THEN
```

when it should be

```
IF nextLine.City = line.City  THEN
```

But I suggest getting rid of the REFERENCING clause and just using :NEW and :OLD in triggers as it reduces confusion. So use

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_BRANCH AS SELECT NumBranch, CITY FROM BRANCH;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkUniqueBranchPerCity
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON BRANCH  
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE TEMP_BRANCH IN ROW SHARE MODE;

   FOR line IN (SELECT * FROM TEMP_BRANCH) LOOP 
     IF :NEW.City = line.City  THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I also suggest you get rid of the DELETE statement in the trigger as it will delete the contents of TEMP_BRANCH the first time the trigger fires.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. Still I think my idea is wrong cause when I update or insert in the branch, no data is inserted or updated in the temp_table wich is a copy of the Branch. So, on the second update or insert the trigger will not notice the mistake. I should find a way to do so withoud creating a duplicate unnecessary tabl